# How to update the Organizational unit IDs with new OUs in cloudformation StackSet

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm facing issues while trying to update the cloudformation stackset with new OU IDs via boto3.

OU Structure: CoreOU -> ConnectOU -> Prod (ou-rhew-abcdef)

**Code:**

```
import boto3

cloudformation_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = cloudformation_client.update_stack_instances(
        StackSetName='AWS-BACKUP-VAULT',
        DeploymentTargets={
            'OrganizationalUnitIds': [
                'ou-rhew-abcdef'
            ]
        },
        Regions=[
            'eu-west-1',
            'eu-central-1',
            'eu-west-2',
            'eu-west-3',
            'eu-north-1',
            'ap-southeast-1',
            'ap-south-1',
            'ap-northeast-2',
            'ap-southeast-2',
            'us-east-2',
            'us-east-1',
            'us-west-2'
        ]
    )
```

I have tried using boto3 api **update_stack_set** as well but it results in the same error.

**ERROR**:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStackInstances operation: Organizational unit ou-rhew-abcdef not found in StackSet.
```

Comment: Hi @SUBHAS, could you please confirm you are running the Stack Set in a management account and your OU ID with no typo?

Comment: @VasylHerman Yes I'm running this is management account and I have double checked the OU ID, it does exist.

Comment: Alright, can you also please open `StackSet Info` and confirm the OU is listed under `Organizational unit IDs` in there?

Comment: @VasylHerman So currently there are different OU IDs in stackset and I want to update it with new OU ID as mentioned in the code. The reason being there will be dynamic OUs created and I want to register these dynamically created OU IDs. Ofcourse the code provided here is just to test if it works to add OU IDs to stackset.

Organizational unit IDs (2)

ID
ou-rhew-745dfgw2
ou-rhew-45tfsww1

Comment: Oh, I see now. Did you try to update the StackSet via AWS console?